# Cross-platform frameworks and high profile applications

Tags: frameworks, cross-platform

I was curious about what cross-platform framework does the developers of high profiles applications such as Photoshop, Guitar Pro, etc; use. They all integrate seamlessly with the OS to the point where you can sometimes assume that the application was developed exclusively for that OS.

I have been programming with Qt for about a year and as far as I know given my knowledge and ability with Qt it's not possible to fully integrate your application with MAC OS. (e.g. see [my unsolved issue with Qt and the MAC OS Dock icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529358/qt-on-mac-os-detecting-a-click-on-the-dock-menu) )

Do they all use proprietary in-house frameworks? I'm I just lacking the necessary 'know-how'to achieve this with Qt? Are there better cross-platform alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the technique of separating functionality and display well, and rewriting the display code for each supported platform.  Do it right, and you can minimize the amount of specific display code.

Since the Windows and Mac OSX user interfaces are different beasts in various different and often subtle ways, it's going to be really hard to find a compatibility library that will make an application look native on both platforms.